# Как устранить ошибку gulp Error: Cannot find module 'sass'?

Tags: html, json, gulp, sass, gulp-sass

Не могу исправить ошибку связанную с ошибкой Error: Cannot find module 'sass', я уже и переустанавливал

```
const gulp        = require('gulp');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync');
const sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));

// Static server
gulp.task('server', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: "src"
        }
    });
});

gulp.task('styles', function() {
    return gulp.src("src/sass/*.+(scss|sass)")
            .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}).on('error', sass.logError))
            .pipe(gulp.dest("src/css"))
            .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch("src/sass/*.+(scss|sass)", gulp.parallel('styles'));
    gulp.watch("src/*.html").on("change", browserSync.reload);
});

gulp.task('default', gulp.parallel('watch', 'server', 'styles'));
```

и ошибка

такая

```
mbp-kirill:project_shop kupuelel$ gulp
Error: Cannot find module 'sass'
Require stack:
- /Users/kupuelel/Documents/html_course/project_4/project_shop/gulpfile.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp-cli/lib/shared/require-or-import.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp-cli/lib/versioned/^4.0.0/index.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp-cli/index.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp-cli/bin/gulp.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/kupuelel/Documents/html_course/project_4/project_shop/gulpfile.js:3:35)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/kupuelel/Documents/html_course/project_4/project_shop/gulpfile.js',
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp-cli/lib/shared/require-or-import.js',
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp-cli/lib/versioned/^4.0.0/index.js',
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp-cli/index.js',
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp-cli/bin/gulp.js'
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, можно попробовать удалить всю папку `node_modules` и написать в cli: `sudo npm install --unsafe-perm=true`.

Еще можно попробовать установить следующим образом:

```
npm install -g gulp-sass
or
npm install --save gulp-sass
```

Comment: спасибо, подскажите, а что такое установить в cli ?

Comment: @KUPUELEL, CLI - командная строка (терминал)

Answer (score 0):

Плагин `gulp-sass` обновился до 5 версии, в связи с этим немного изменился принцип его подключения.

Для корректной работы таска `styles` нужно дополнительно установить пакет `sass`:

```
npm i sass --save-dev
```